# what is difference to use or not to use parenths before function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

What is difference between following code?

Code 1:

```
var f = function() {

  // function body code
  // ...
  // ...

}();
```

Code 2:

```
var f = (function(){

  // function body code
  // ...
  // ...

})();
```

Which one is better to use?

Comment: Check this article: [An Important Pair of Parens](http://michaux.ca/articles/an-important-pair-of-parens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent. The second one might be more clear, though.

Answer (score 0):

They're exactly equivalent given the syntax of the language.

Comment: True. It might be worth it to note that both snippits are setting 'f' to the result of a self-executing anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Since it would be invalid syntax without the assignment, as in

```
function() {
    // ...
}();
```

it may be clearer to always wrap anonymous functions in parentheses.